# Modifying row index javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is able to **sort** the columns and it is working fine.

The rows in the table consists of ***parent and child rows*** which when click on the parent row will show the child rows. Otherwise the child rows will remain hidden.

I intend to sort the rows based on the **parent** rows but not the child rows result or else the table will be a mess. I try to use jQuery to **remove all the child rows** before sorting and append them after the sorting function but the sorting function for the column wont work for the second time. This could be the row indexes had messed up. I suspect this happened because when I **remove and store child rows** in a variable, the row indexes still remain. So when I *re-insert the child rows* based on the parent rows, the row indexes of those child rows will remain same.

Is there anyway to explicitly modify the row index of the rows without swapping their positions? 
Tried to use jQuery in such way as:

`$('tr.child-row')[0].rowIndex = 3`

But it just wont work.

Comment: A code snippet will be better to give you the solution. By this it is hard to understand how you are sorting the table.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @virenKalkhudiya the code i involved in the project has a rather huge size of table and consist a lot of explicit table functions, so it could take me some time to make a code snippet to mimic the current situation

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of two rows in a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/4v2owx37/2

This is a simple code that changes order of two rows.

```
function swap_position(first_index, second_index){

  if(second_index > first_index){
    $("tr").eq(first_index).insertBefore($("tr").eq(second_index));
    $("tr").eq(second_index).insertBefore($("tr").eq(first_index));
  }

  else if(first_index > second_index){
    $("tr").eq(second_index).insertBefore($("tr").eq(first_index));
    $("tr").eq(first_index).insertBefore($("tr").eq(second_index));
  }

}

swap_position(1,4);
swap_position(5,3);
```

Comment: This is really good example of swapping the rows of the table! 
However, Im facing a problem where I actually first _take out all the child rows_, and **re-insert** them based on the parents because I dont want the data on child row's columns to be included when _sorting_

Comment: After I reinsert the child rows based on the parents row, it seems nothing wrong. 
But I have checked their own respective row indexes and find out the row indexes of the _child rows_ remain as same before I sort them.
I suspect this happened when I stored them before sorting them so the row indexes remain same as before.